# Ext JS 4.2 Incorrect Row index in the grouping

Tags: javascript, extjs, grouping

I am using a grid with action columns. Recently I added grouping feature. Now I am getting incorrect row index if I collapse one or more groups above my selection. ie when there is a collapsed group all the rows inside the group are not accounted for calculating row index.

Below is my action column handler

```
{
    iconCls: 'download',
    align: 'center',
    tooltip: 'Download File',
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex) {

        console.log(rowIndex, colIndex);

        var rec = grid.getStore().getAt(rowIndex);

        // need to find the correct record                                  
    }
}
```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using a bufferedRenderer on the grid?

Comment: Yes I am using bufferedRenderer

Comment: You can turn off the buffered renderer if you don't have a crazy amount of records in the store. That would solve your calculation issue.

Comment: Thx for your reply. Unfortunately, I have large amount of records in the store. Not able to turn off. In this case, is this a bug in Ext JS 4.2.x?

Comment: It's the bufferedRenderer. It doesn't create it on the grid until you scroll down. You could get the store with the data and do you calculations there as all the records are in the store.  In Extjs5 they kind of fixed this by allowing formulas in the model itself.
You might want to try findRecord and do an index of this record on the store to get the correct position. It would be the same as the grid.

Answer (score 1):

If you only need to get your record, that information is already a parameter of your handler. If you really need the index, use that parameter to query your store.

```
{
    iconCls: 'download',
    align: 'center',
    tooltip: 'Download File',
    handler: function(grid, rowIndex, colIndex, item, e, record) {

        var recIndex = grid.getStore().indexOf(record);

        console.log(recIndex);
    }
}
```

Comment: Like JesseRules said, if you don't use BufferedRenderer then it gives you correct record. Fails with BufferedRenderer

Answer (score -1):

```
{//var recIndex = grid.getStore().indexOf(record); //console.log(recIndex); 
    //the solution    

    var indexRecord = item.attributes[1].nodeValue;     

     var recIndex = grid.store.data.indexMap[indexRecord];         
       //recIndex is the true index of the record                        
       //if you need the record of that Index, add this code           
         record = grid.getStore().getAt(recIndex );                         
}
```